# Specifying papersize for md to pdf conversion

Tags: pandoc

I've read you can specify papersize by [`pandoc -V papersize:"a4paper" ...`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/600).  This doesn't seem to work anymore.  I've managed to specify `B5` using

```
pandoc -V papersize:b5 -o out.pdf in.md
```

But this fails for e.g. `b6`.  The following `-V` arguments also all appear to have no effect:

```
-V papersize:b5paper
-V papersize:"b5paper"
-V "papersize:b5paper"
```

What is the proper way to format this, or am I missing something more fundamental?  In my opinion [the documentation](http://pandoc.org/README.html#creating-a-pdf) is far from clear, lacking e.g. any examples.

Answer (score 21):

```
pandoc -s -V papersize:a4
```

[Pandoc's LaTeX template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) will append `paper` to `a4`...

Comment: Well the default is I think a4.  But `pandoc -V papersize:b6 ...` doesn't work despite being a legitimate Latex size..

Comment: it should work... try `-s -o out.tex` instead of `-o out.pdf` to see the LaTeX pandoc generates...

Comment: Is there a way to have the width of the paper match A4 but the page to have infinite length (Namely don't cut the MD file into pages, just long page as it looks in HTML)?

Comment: @Royi make your own pandoc latex template (or use `header-includes`) and see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/automatically-increase-pdf-page-height

Comment: What if I'm OK with setting the length myself? Does PanDoc supports that?

Comment: @Royi pandoc just calls LaTeX for the PDF so it supports everything LaTeX does. see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf and if necessary ask a new question on tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9):

You can use either `-V papersize:a4` [per the manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex) or `-V geometry:a4paper`. The latter has a side-effect of giving smaller margins than the default template.

Comment: Is there a way to have the width of the paper match A4 but the page to have infinite length (Namely don't cut the MD file into pages, just long page as it looks in HTML)?

Answer (score 5):

In order to control **papersize and margins** you could run something along the lines of:

```
pandoc -V geometry:a4paper,margin=2cm in.md -o out.pdf
```

(you may try other options of the geometry.sty latex package)

Comment: Combining paper geometry with margins is just fantastic!

Answer (score 3):

```
pandoc -V geometry:b5paper infile -o outfile.pdf
```

Using 'geometry' worked for me.

I presume the options [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins) under 'Reference guide' would work (but I haven't tested).